# Submodule NameError Rspec

Tags: ruby, module, loading, rspec2

I'm trying to have a file require specific files in some subdirectories, but I keep getting a name error, when I run `rspec` in the root directory:

`song_spec.rb:3:in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Songify::Entities (NameError)`

My directory structure:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── songify
│   │   ├── entities
│   │   │   └── song.rb
│   └── songify.rb
└── spec
    ├── entities
    │   └── song_spec.rb
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

`song_spec.rb` source:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper.rb'

describe Songify::Entities::Song do
end
```

`spec_helper.rb` requires `/lib/songify.rb` which in turn requires the files in the `entity subdirectory`.

`spec_helper.rb` source:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative '../lib/songify.rb'
```

`songify.rb` source:

```
module Songify
end

Dir["./songify/entities/*"].each {|file| require_relative file}
```

I've tested that the requires are actually happening in `songify.rb` through puts statements in the entity file.

Source for `/lib/entities/song.rb` here:

```
module Songify
  module Entities
    class Song
    end
  end
end
```

This is driving me insane... anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: My feeling leads me to believe it's because my spec dir tree doesn't match my lib tree...

Ediit 2: The autoloading is in some way to blame. If I use a regular require_relative call with the relative path to song.rb rspec runs with no issue.. Hmm..

Comment: Is this a rails app, rails engine or library? How are requiring your `lib` directory?

Comment: Have you tried `Dir["./songify/entities/*.rb"].each {|file| require file}` using require instead of require_relative?

Comment: @Ken this is just a vanilla ruby project, the lib dir is required by the spec_helper.rb fle

Comment: @JarodAdair yeah, the inclusion of the ext doesn't seem to affect it at all. If I did just * operator, I would get the full filename with the extension.  Also, there are no hidden files in that directory getting accidentally included, and it isn't including .. or .

Comment: @JarodAdair Ah, to answer your actual question - `require` does not work